# запрос о выводе самого элементов с самой ранней датой

Tags: sql

Есть таблица хранящая линии покупки: Sales: Id, ProductId, CustomerId, DateCreated. Мы хотим понять, через какие продукты клиенты «попадают» к нам в магазин. Как мог бы выглядеть запрос, который выводит продукт и количество случаев, когда он был первой покупкой клиента.

Answer (score 2):

Укажите СУБД.

А вообще примерно так:

```
SELECT ProductId, COUNT(*) as Cnt
FROM(
  SELECT ProductId, CustomerId, DateCreated, 
    MIN(DateCreated)OVER(PARTITION BY   CustomerId)MinDate
  FROM Sales
)as T
WHERE DateCreated = MinDate
GROUP BY ProductId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Если нет оконных функций, то так:

```
SELECT S.ProductId, COUNT(*) as Cnt
FROM(
  SELECT CustomerId,  
    MIN(DateCreated)MinDate
  FROM Sales
  GROUP BY CustomerId
)as T JOIN Sales as S ON S.CustomerId = T.CustomerId 
  AND S.MinDate=S.DateCreated
GROUP BY S.ProductId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Нужно еще вывести количество раз.

Comment: @newman, добавил